# org-agenda-span to display the 3 days of yesterday, today and tomorrow

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am reading [The Org Manual: Weekly/daily agenda](https://orgmode.org/manual/Weekly_002fdaily-agenda.html#Weekly_002fdaily-agenda)
and customized the variable `org-agenda-span` as 3

The agenda then displayed the three days of  today and the next two days.

I think it better to display the  3 days as "yesterday, today and tomorrow`.

Is it possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved the same by setting the variable `org-agenda-start-day` to `-1` in one of my custom agenda commands.

Hope this helps.